# Como instalar o mingw-w64-x86_64-GCC com MSYS2 se recebo a mensagem que mingw64 já está instalado no sistema

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys2, cygwin

Estou tentando instalar o GCC em minha estação Windows para fazer novos testes com o uso do GCC e alguns programas compilados em C que podem ser portados para o Windows.

Eu já usei diversas versões do GCC para o Windows, algumas baseadas em CygWin outras no próprio Mingw, mas agora estou querendo concentrar tudo em no MSys2.

Porém mesmo depois de ter removido todas as aplicações não estou conseguindo instalar o GCC com Msys2.

Estou usando o seguinteo comando

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

Então recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
resolvendo dependências...
procurando por pacotes conflitantes...
atenção: dependência cíclica detectada:
atenção: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran será instalado antes de sua dependência mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs

Pacotes (16) mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils-2.27-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2-1.0.6-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git-5.0.0.4745.d2384c2-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran-6.2.0-2
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-6.2.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp-6.1.1-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git-5.0.0.4747.0f8f626-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-isl-0.17.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv-1.14-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc-1.0.3-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr-3.1.4.p3-4
             mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest-6.4-2
             mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib-1.2.8-9  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-6.2.0-2

Tamanho total instalado:  357,21 MiB

:: Continuar a instalação? [S/n] S
(16/16) verificando chaves no chaveiro             [#####################] 100%
(16/16) verificando integridade do pacote          [#####################] 100%
(16/16) carregando arquivos do pacote              [#####################] 100%
(16/16) verificando conflitos de arquivo           [#####################] 100%
erro: falha em submeter a transação (arquivos conflitantes)
mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-isl: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc: /mingw64 existe no sistema de arquivos
Ocorreram erros e, portanto, nenhum pacote foi atualizado.

consu_000@SocialSLA MSYS ~
```

O que devo fazer para resolver tal problema?

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tal problema basta criar uma pasta de nome `mingw64` no raiz quando executando o shell do MSys2.

Este problema afeta a versão 64Bits que espera existir o diretório para fazer a instalação dos pacotes.

veja abaixo:

```
consu_000@SocialSLA MSYS ~
$ mkdir /mingw64

consu_000@SocialSLA MSYS ~
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
resolvendo dependências...
procurando por pacotes conflitantes...
atenção: dependência cíclica detectada:
atenção: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran será instalado antes de sua dependência mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs

Pacotes (16) mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils-2.27-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2-1.0.6-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git-5.0.0.4745.d2384c2-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran-6.2.0-2
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-6.2.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp-6.1.1-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git-5.0.0.4747.0f8f626-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-isl-0.17.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv-1.14-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc-1.0.3-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr-3.1.4.p3-4
             mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest-6.4-2
             mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib-1.2.8-9  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-6.2.0-2

Tamanho total instalado:  357,21 MiB

:: Continuar a instalação? [S/n] S
(16/16) verificando chaves no chaveiro             [#####################] 100%
(16/16) verificando integridade do pacote          [#####################] 100%
(16/16) carregando arquivos do pacote              [#####################] 100%
(16/16) verificando conflitos de arquivo           [#####################] 100%
(16/16) verificando espaço em disco disponível     [#####################] 100%
:: Processando alterações do pacote...
( 1/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv       [#####################] 100%
( 2/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp            [#####################] 100%
( 3/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthr...  [#####################] 100%
( 4/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfo...  [#####################] 100%
( 5/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs       [#####################] 100%
( 6/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2          [#####################] 100%
( 7/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib           [#####################] 100%
( 8/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils       [#####################] 100%
( 9/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git    [#####################] 100%
(10/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git        [#####################] 100%
(11/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-isl            [#####################] 100%
(12/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr           [#####################] 100%
(13/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc            [#####################] 100%
(14/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-de...  [#####################] 100%
(15/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthread...  [#####################] 100%
(16/16) instalando mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc            [#####################] 100%

consu_000@SocialSLA MSYS ~
```